# Return loop output to table (PHP)

Tags: php, function, loops

I'm probably making a very basic error but I'm quite new to this.

I have a table where I need to edit what is displayed in each box using variables but I'm having trouble with getting the outputs into the table. Experimentation helped me work out the first box but I can't get the second one working because I think the function is written incorrectly. I need a conditional loop that displays all even numbers between 10 and 20 (the code below doesn't have anything to do with even numbers at the moment I'm just trying to get it to work)

```
<?php

$random = rand() . srand(3034);

function loop() {
    for ($i = 10; $i <= 20; $i++) {
      $loop = $i;
      return $loop;
    }
}

echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
       <td>Box 1 - ".$random."</td>
       <td>Box 2 - ".$loop."</td>
      </tr>

     </table> ";
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The whole thing is not useful. `$loop` gets overwritten in every iteration of `$i`, but as there is a `return` the loop does not work at all, it quits straight after the first time it runs. So the return of the function (which you arent calling btw!) will always be `10`. You would instead echo the `<tr>`'s within the loop and not return inside the loop. It seems you might want to look into PHP basics first.

Comment: Read about [variable scope](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), your `$loop` is only available inside your function `loop()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop on the  tags itself, because the return condition in the loop breaks it to only 1 iteration.

So you should do it like this:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>Box 1 - ".$random."</td>";
for ($i = 10; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    echo "<td>Box 2 - ".$i."</td>";
}
echo"</tr>";
```

Comment: I see, so it would not be possible to define the function outside the table and then have it executed within the table?

Comment: @codenoob nope there is no idea to make it like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to my comment here is some more code:

```
<?php
$random = rand() . srand(3034);

function loop($randomNumber) {
    for ($loop = 10; $loop <= 20; $loop++) {
        echo
            '<tr>' .
            '<td>Box 1 - ' . $randomNumber . '</td>' . 
            '<td>Box 2 - ' . $loop . '</td>' . 
            '</tr>';
    }
}

echo
    '<table border="1">' . 
    loop($random) . 
    '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 

    function loop(){
         $return = '';
         for($i = 10; $i <=20; $i++){
              $random = rand() . srand(3034);
              if($i%2==0){
                 $return.='<tr>
                           <td>Box 1 - '.$random.'</td>
                           <td>Box 2 - '.$i.'</td>
                          </tr>';
              }
         }
        return $return;
    }

    echo '<table>'.loop().'</table>';
```